# Adding rules to running stream (tweepy, streamingClient)

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to collect all Tweets of certain users and the replies to those Tweets. Collecting the original Tweets works out fine, but collecting the replies does not. As soon as on_tweet is called (when the stream receives a Tweet), I am trying to add a rule 'in_reply_to_tweet_id: 'id of incoming tweet'' to my stream so that it also stream those replies. Yet the code below doesn't work. I checked with get_rules after the stream was closed and there was no rule added. I also tried adding a simple 'OR: keyword' rule, which was also not added, so the ID is not the problem.
Thanks, any help is appreciated!:)

```py
class stream(tweepy.StreamingClient):   
    def __init__(self, token):
        tweepy.StreamingClient.__init__(self, token)
        
        self.raw_tweets = []
        self.raw_replies = []
         
    #this method is called whenever the stream receives a tweet
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        
        #checking whether new tweet in stream is a original tweet or a  reply to a tweet
        if (tweet.conversation_id == tweet.id):

          
            #add the id to the rules so that replies to the tweet are also streamed
            #this is where the problem is
            id_as_str = str(tweet.id)
            new_rule = 'OR in_reply_to_tweet_id:' + id_as_str
            self.add_rules(add= tweepy.StreamRule(new_rule), dry_run = True)
            self.raw_tweets.append(tweet)
            
            print('this is an original'+tweet.text)

        else:
            
            self.raw_replies.append(tweet)
            print('this is a reply:'+tweet.text)

        return self.raw_tweets
```